# Keeping track of git repositories locally

Tags: osx, git

I want to keep track of git repositories located on remote servers (not local repositories).

**What I need**

Get notifications when commits are made, and what was changed (something like "new commit made, #commithash"): A notification in the notification center. A popup. A feed/RSS update. Anything just not email.

**Currently what I am doing**

Using SourceTree, I create a local clone.

Whenever there is a commit, I get a notification. I can what was changed in the commit.

**Problem**

It takes too much space on disk (currently over 1gb)

Answer (score 1):

If the remote repositories are on github you can use the integrations they have built with [slack](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201824286-Setting-up-the-GitHub-app) or [HipChat](https://blog.hipchat.com/2014/06/12/introducing-the-new-github-for-hipchat-add-on/) to accomplish this.  I have been using the slack/github integration for six months and my only complaint is that I have to specify each repo instead of being able to use wild cards.